# How can I upgrade windows workflow templates from VS2010 to VS2012?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

We have created workflow templates in VS2010 and want to upgrade the templates to VS2012. Using the same templates in VS2012 are ending up with errors. How to go on this? We are using side by side versions of VS 2010 and 2012.

Comment: *Using the same templates in VS2012 are ending up with errors.* No they aren't.  I don't see a single error in your question.  Obviously you're fibbing.

Comment: I mean to say that Once I open the templates (which were edited in VS 2010 to add custom activities) in VS 2012, I find the errors  (in red). That's what I mean.

Comment: Nope, I still don't see any errors.  So I believe you are lying.  Of course, you could [edit] your question and add these actual errors in to prove me wrong.  The errors that, without which, it is utterly and completely impossible to answer your question.  It's like going to the doctor and saying "I'm sick" and the doctor going "well, what's wrong?" and you reply "NOPE."

Comment: Nothing to lie in this. This is a .net framework error where I came across in below link. Im helped with the link: http://pragmaticpattern.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/opening-a-tfs-2010-build-process-template-in-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: Next time, put the error in your question, or don't bother at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the .net framework. I was using .net framework 3.5 and the required is 4.5 for VS2012. Link http://pragmaticpattern.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/opening-a-tfs-2010-build-process-template-in-visual-studio-2012/ helped.